# Navigating to pages with the AppBar with MvvmLight, WinRt

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, mvvm-light

I have a top app bar customer user control that is used to navigate in my WinRt MvvmLight application. This custom control is added to all my pages

**TopAppBar User Control**

```
<AppBarButton 
 x:Uid="HomeTopAppBar"
 Command="{Binding HomeCommand}"
 Icon="Home"/>
<AppBarButton 
 x:Uid="LibraryTopAppBar"
 Command="{Binding LibraryCommand}"
 Icon="Library"/>
```

These commands are added to all my ViewModels. For example,

**HomeViewModel**

```
public RelayCommand LibraryCommand {
  get {
     return new RelayCommand(
                 () => _navigationService.Navigate(typeof(LibraryPage)));
  }
}

public RelayCommand HomeCommand {
   get {
      return new RelayCommand(
                 () => _navigationService.Navigate(typeof(HomePage)));
   }
}
```

The problem I'm having is that if the user uses the top app bar, the first click works (i.e., the user is navigated to the correct page.) On the second click, the program crashes in NavigationHelper on the OnNavigatedFrom method (taken from MvvmLight). The program complains that the _pageKey is null. Is there something that I'm doing incorrectly? How exactly does a user navigate to other pages from the App Bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding a command in my Appbar, i decided to use a click event. The reason why i did this is because by using the command, every viewmodel that uses my appbar needs to create that command. Here is my solution:

**TopAppBar.xaml**

```
<AppBarButton 
  x:Uid="HomeTopAppBar"
  Click="AppBarButton_Home"
  Icon="Home"/>
<AppBarButton 
  x:Uid="LibraryTopAppBar"
  Click="AppBarButton_Library"
  Icon="Library"/>
```

**TopAppBar.xaml.cs**

```
private void AppBarButton_Home(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
   SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<INavigationService>().Navigate(typeof(HomePage));
}

private void AppBarButton_Library(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
  SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<INavigationService>().Navigate(typeof(LibraryPage));
}
```

**Any page navigated to from Appbar (Ex. HomePage)**

```
public sealed partial class HomePage {
  public HomePage() {
     InitializeComponent();
  }

  public HomeViewModel ViewModel {
     get {
        return (HomeViewModel)DataContext;
     }
  }

  //needed for navigation
  protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e) {
     base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
  }

  //needed for navigation
  protected override void OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationEventArgs e) {
     base.OnNavigatedFrom(e);
  }

}
```